# conversion of string into int array

Tags: query-string

Actually I need to convert string data (string s="76473") into int array (int[]={7,6,4,7,3})
also want to know how can I got it by 2 or 3 numbers like {76,47,03} / {764,073}
thanks

Comment: Which programming language do you need to use?

Answer (score 0):

Take the string, and for languages like java, c, and many other languages there is a function **Integer.ParseInt**(s.[0]); //in java, in c the function would be **atoi**  Where we would treat the string like a character array and take the character at the 0th position.  Then we can throw that into an array:

```
int[] array = new array[...];
for (int i = 0; i< s.length;i++){    
array[n] = Integer.ParseInt(s[n]);
}
```

The second part of that question, you would then take the elements of the array to create groups.  Depending on how you subdividing you will get different numbers.